# Properties of tensor $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\lambda$

Tags: tensor-calculus, dirac-matrices

As the title suggests, I am trying to derive some properties of the tensor $\Gamma^{\mu\nu\lambda}=\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\lambda$. My motivation is that $\bar{\psi}\Gamma^{\mu\nu\lambda}\psi$ should not create any more Dirac bilinears, meaning that it should be reducible to the existing one $1$, $\gamma^\mu$, $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu$.

Using anticommutation relation of gamma-matrices I managed to prove that

$\Gamma^{\mu\nu\lambda}=2\eta^{\mu\nu}\gamma^\lambda-\Gamma^{\nu\mu\lambda}$

And similar identities. Also, I derived that

$tr\,\Gamma^{\mu\nu\lambda}=0$

$\Gamma^{\mu\,\nu}_{\,\mu}=D\gamma^{\nu}$

How do I reduce the tensor and why doesn't it create more Dirac bilinears?

Comment: Do you fully appreciate [identity 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Miscellaneous_identities)?

Comment: Oh, I did not notice it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To analyze $\Gamma^{\mu \nu \rho}$, it is useful to think about different cases. When two of the three indices are equal, it should reduce to a single gamma matrix. When the three indices are different, it should reduce to a completely antisymmetric tensor. Thus, it is natural to expect something of the form
$$ \Gamma^{\mu \nu \rho} \sim \eta \gamma + \epsilon^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} M_\sigma $$
Going in this direction and checking explicitly some cases, you'll find
$$ \Gamma^{\mu \nu \rho} = \eta^{\mu \nu}\gamma^\rho + \eta^{\nu \rho} \gamma^\mu - \eta^{\mu \rho} \gamma^\nu  - i \epsilon^{\sigma \mu \nu \rho} \gamma_\sigma \gamma^5 $$
as mentioned in Wikipedia.